# Summernote('code') is not working for pulling the data

Tags: summernote

```js
scope.initializeSummernote = function() {
        $('.summernoteWYSWIG').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Enter your message place images and                 videos...',
            onChange: scope.updateMessage
        });
    };
    
    var summernoteVariable = $('.summernoteWYSWIG').summernote('code');
```

```css
@font-face{font-family:"summernote";font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;src:url("font/summernote.eot?546c01739436985e5a21a8cb325521f3");src:url("font/summernote.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),url("font/summernote.woff?546c01739436985e5a21a8cb325521f3") format("woff"),url("font/summernote.ttf?546c01739436985e5a21a8cb325521f3") format("truetype")}[class^="note-icon-"]:before,[class*=" note-icon-"]:before{display:inline-block;font:normal normal normal 14px summernote;font-size:inherit;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;text-decoration:inherit;text-rendering:auto;text-transform:none;vertical-align:middle;speak:none;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}.note-icon-align-center:before{content:"\f101"}.note-icon-align-indent:before{content:"\f102"}.note-icon-align-justify:before{content:"\f103"}.note-icon-align-left:before{content:"\f104"}.note-icon-align-outdent:before{content:"\f105"}.note-icon-align-right:before{content:"\f106"}.note-icon-align:before{content:"\f107"}.note-icon-arrows-alt:before{content:"\f108"}.note-icon-bold:before{content:"\f109"}.note-icon-caret:before{content:"\f10a"}.note-icon-chain-broken:before{content:"\f10b"}.note-icon-circle:before{content:"\f10c"}.note-icon-close:before{content:"\f10d"}.note-icon-code:before{content:"\f10e"}.note-icon-eraser:before{content:"\f10f"}.note-icon-font:before{content:"\f110"}.note-icon-frame:before{content:"\f111"}.note-icon-italic:before{content:"\f112"}.note-icon-link:before{content:"\f113"}.note-icon-magic:before{content:"\f114"}.note-icon-menu-check:before{content:"\f115"}.note-icon-minus:before{content:"\f116"}.note-icon-orderedlist:before{content:"\f117"}.note-icon-pencil:before{content:"\f118"}.note-icon-picture:before{content:"\f119"}.note-icon-question:before{content:"\f11a"}.note-icon-redo:before{content:"\f11b"}.note-icon-special-character:before{content:"\f11c"}.note-icon-square:before{content:"\f11d"}.note-icon-strikethrough:before{content:"\f11e"}.note-icon-subscript:before{content:"\f11f"}.note-icon-summernote:before{content:"\f120"}.note-icon-superscript:before{content:"\f121"}.note-icon-table:before{content:"\f122"}.note-icon-text-height:before{content:"\f123"}.note-icon-trash:before{content:"\f124"}.note-icon-underline:before{content:"\f125"}.note-icon-undo:before{content:"\f126"}.note-icon-unorderedlist:before{content:"\f127"}.note-icon-video:before{content:"\f128"}.note-editor{position:relative}.note-editor .note-dropzone{position:absolute;z-index:100;display:none;color:#87cefa;background-color:white;opacity:.95}.note-editor .note-dropzone .note-dropzone-message{display:table-cell;font-size:28px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}.note-editor .note-dropzone.hover{color:#098ddf}.note-editor.dragover .note-dropzone{display:table}.note-editor .note-editing-area{position:relative}.note-editor .note-editing-area .note-editable{outline:0}.note-editor .note-editing-area .note-editable sup{vertical-align:super}.note-editor .note-editing-area .note-editable sub{vertical-align:sub}.note-editor.note-frame{border:1px solid #a9a9a9}.note-editor.note-frame.codeview .note-editing-area .note-editable{display:none}.note-editor.note-frame.codeview .note-editing-area .note-codable{display:block}.note-editor.note-frame .note-editing-area{overflow:hidden}.note-editor.note-frame .note-editing-area .note-editable{padding:10px;overflow:auto;color:#000;background-color:#fff}.note-editor.note-frame .note-editing-area .note-editable[contenteditable="false"]{background-color:#e5e5e5}.note-editor.note-frame .note-editing-area .note-codable{display:none;width:100%;padding:10px;margin-bottom:0;font-family:Menlo,Monaco,monospace,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#ccc;background-color:#222;border:0;-webkit-border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0;border-radius:0;box-shadow:none;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;resize:none}.note-editor.note-frame.fullscreen{position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:1050;width:100%!important}.note-editor.note-frame.fullscreen .note-editable{background-color:white}.note-editor.note-frame.fullscreen .note-resizebar{display:none}.note-editor.note-frame .note-statusbar{background-color:#f5f5f5;border-bottom-right-radius:4px;border-bottom-left-radius:4px}.note-editor.note-frame .note-statusbar .note-resizebar{width:100%;height:8px;padding-top:1px;cursor:ns-resize}.note-editor.note-frame .note-statusbar .note-resizebar .note-icon-bar{width:20px;margin:1px auto;border-top:1px solid #a9a9a9}.note-editor.note-frame .note-placeholder{padding:10px}.note-popover.popover{max-width:none}.note-popover.popover .popover-content a{display:inline-block;max-width:200px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;vertical-align:middle}.note-popover.popover .arrow{left:20px!important}.note-popover .popover-content,.panel-heading.note-toolbar{padding:0 0 5px 5px;margin:0}.note-popover .popover-content>.btn-group,.panel-heading.note-toolbar>.btn-group{margin-top:5px;margin-right:5px;margin-left:0}.note-popover .popover-content .btn-group .note-table,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .btn-group .note-table{min-width:0;padding:5px}.note-popover .popover-content .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker{font-size:18px}.note-popover .popover-content .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-mousecatcher,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-mousecatcher{position:absolute!important;z-index:3;width:10em;height:10em;cursor:pointer}.note-popover .popover-content .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-unhighlighted,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-unhighlighted{position:relative!important;z-index:1;width:5em;height:5em;background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASAgMAAAAroGbEAAAACVBMVEUAAIj4+Pjp6ekKlAqjAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfYAR0BKhmnaJzPAAAAG0lEQVQI12NgAAOtVatWMTCohoaGUY+EmIkEAEruEzK2J7tvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') repeat}.note-popover .popover-content .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-highlighted,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .btn-group .note-table .note-dimension-picker .note-dimension-picker-highlighted{position:absolute!important;z-index:2;width:1em;height:1em;background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABIAAAASAgMAAAAroGbEAAAACVBMVEUAAIjd6vvD2f9LKLW+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAFiS0dEAIgFHUgAAAAJcEhZcwAACxMAAAsTAQCanBgAAAAHdElNRQfYAR0BKwNDEVT0AAAAG0lEQVQI12NgAAOtVatWMTCohoaGUY+EmIkEAEruEzK2J7tvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') repeat}.note-popover .popover-content .note-style h1,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style h1,.note-popover .popover-content .note-style h2,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style h2,.note-popover .popover-content .note-style h3,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style h3,.note-popover .popover-content .note-style h4,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style h4,.note-popover .popover-content .note-style h5,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style h5,.note-popover .popover-content .note-style h6,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style h6,.note-popover .popover-content .note-style blockquote,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-style blockquote{margin:0}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-toggle,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-toggle{width:20px;padding-left:5px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu{min-width:340px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group{margin:0}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group:first-child,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group:first-child{margin:0 5px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-palette-title,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-palette-title{margin:2px 7px;font-size:12px;text-align:center;border-bottom:1px solid #eee}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-reset,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-reset{width:100%;padding:0 3px;margin:3px;font-size:11px;cursor:pointer;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-row,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-row{height:20px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-reset:hover,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color .dropdown-menu .btn-group .note-color-reset:hover{background:#eee}.note-popover .popover-content .note-para .dropdown-menu,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-para .dropdown-menu{min-width:216px;padding:5px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-para .dropdown-menu>div:first-child,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-para .dropdown-menu>div:first-child{margin-right:5px}.note-popover .popover-content .dropdown-menu,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .dropdown-menu{min-width:90px}.note-popover .popover-content .dropdown-menu.right,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .dropdown-menu.right{right:0;left:auto}.note-popover .popover-content .dropdown-menu.right::before,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .dropdown-menu.right::before{right:9px;left:auto!important}.note-popover .popover-content .dropdown-menu.right::after,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .dropdown-menu.right::after{right:10px;left:auto!important}.note-popover .popover-content .dropdown-menu.note-check li a i,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .dropdown-menu.note-check li a i{color:deepskyblue;visibility:hidden}.note-popover .popover-content .dropdown-menu.note-check li a.checked i,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .dropdown-menu.note-check li a.checked i{visibility:visible}.note-popover .popover-content .note-fontsize-10,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-fontsize-10{font-size:10px}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color-palette,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color-palette{line-height:1}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color-palette div .note-color-btn,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color-palette div .note-color-btn{width:20px;height:20px;padding:0;margin:0;border:1px solid #fff}.note-popover .popover-content .note-color-palette div .note-color-btn:hover,.panel-heading.note-toolbar .note-color-palette div .note-color-btn:hover{border:1px solid #000}.note-dialog>div{display:none}.note-dialog .form-group{margin-right:0;margin-left:0}.note-dialog .note-modal-form{margin:0}.note-dialog .note-image-dialog .note-dropzone{min-height:100px;margin-bottom:10px;font-size:30px;line-height:4;color:lightgray;text-align:center;border:4px dashed lightgray}@-moz-document url-prefix(){.note-image-input{height:auto}}.note-placeholder{position:absolute;display:none;color:gray}.note-handle .note-control-selection{position:absolute;display:none;border:1px solid black}.note-handle .note-control-selection>div{position:absolute}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-selection-bg{width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;-webkit-opacity:.3;-khtml-opacity:.3;-moz-opacity:.3;opacity:.3;-ms-filter:alpha(opacity=30);filter:alpha(opacity=30)}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-handle{width:7px;height:7px;border:1px solid black}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-holder{width:7px;height:7px;border:1px solid black}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-sizing{width:7px;height:7px;background-color:white;border:1px solid black}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-nw{top:-5px;left:-5px;border-right:0;border-bottom:0}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-ne{top:-5px;right:-5px;border-bottom:0;border-left:none}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-sw{bottom:-5px;left:-5px;border-top:0;border-right:0}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-se{right:-5px;bottom:-5px;cursor:se-resize}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-se.note-control-holder{cursor:default;border-top:0;border-left:none}.note-handle .note-control-selection .note-control-selection-info{right:0;bottom:0;padding:5px;margin:5px;font-size:12px;color:white;background-color:black;-webkit-border-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;-webkit-opacity:.7;-khtml-opacity:.7;-moz-opacity:.7;opacity:.7;-ms-filter:alpha(opacity=70);filter:alpha(opacity=70)}.note-hint-popover{min-width:100px;padding:2px}.note-hint-popover .popover-content{max-height:150px;padding:3px;overflow:auto}.note-hint-popover .popover-content .note-hint-group .note-hint-item{display:block!important;padding:3px}.note-hint-popover .popover-content .note-hint-group .note-hint-item.active,.note-hint-popover .popover-content .note-hint-group .note-hint-item:hover{display:block;clear:both;font-weight:400;line-height:1.4;color:white;text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;cursor:pointer;background-color:#428bca;outline:0}
```

```html
<div class="summernote-wrapper msg_box" ng-init="initializeSummernote()">
                                                <textarea name="text" class="summernoteWYSWIG" id="contents" ng-model="message" ng-keyup="createMessage()" title="Contents"></textarea>
                                            </div>
```

I'm using summernote-0.8.3 version.
summernote('code') is not pulling the data from the editor.Please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Write a function like this to decode html**

```
htmlDecode(str){
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.innerHTML = str;
 return div.textContent || div.innerText;
}
```

**Then pull the data using the code like below...**

```
htmlDecode($('.summernote').summernote('code'));
```